# Await for observable inside method in Unit test Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have folowing code:

app.component.specs.ts:

```
  it('should upload files and add links to array', async () => {
    const files = new TestFileList() as any as FileList;
    component.uploadFiles(files);
    await new Promise((resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)));
    expect(component.photoUrls.length).toEqual(files.length);
  });
}
```

app.component.ts

```
uploadFiles(files: FileList) {
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      this.photoService.uploadPhoto(files.item(i)).subscribe(data => this.photoUrls.push(data.link), error => alert(error));
    }
  }
```

Promise for timeout in app.component.specs.ts not looks good. How can I await untill all files whill be uploaded and links added to array in other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting, I have yet to deal with a situation like this. But usually, I re-use a utility function called `waitUntil`.

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
.....
export const waitUntil = async (untilTruthy: Function): Promise<boolean> => {
  while (!untilTruthy()) {
    await interval(25).pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
  }
  return Promise.resolve(true);
};
```

You can set the time to whatever you like, I just defaulted it to 25ms.

```
it('should upload files and add links to array', async (done) => {
    const files = new TestFileList() as any as FileList;
    component.uploadFiles(files);
    await waitUntil(() => component.photoUrls.length === files.length);
    // you may not have to do the following assertion because we waited for it to be true
    expect(component.photoUrls.length).toEqual(files.length);
    done();
  });
```

This way, we are not dependent on time (`setTimeOut of 5s`) but we just keep looping until the condition becomes truthy and then carry on with our assertions. I think this reads better.

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this. Let me know if it not works?

```
 it('should upload files and add links to array' , inject([PhotoService] , fakeAsync((photoService : PhotoService) => {
    const files = new TestFileList() as any as FileList;
    spyOn(photoService ,'uploadPhoto').and.returnValue(of('http://image1.jpeg'));
    component.uploadFiles(files);
    tick(3000);
    expect(component.photoUrls.length).toEqual(files.length);
  })));
```

Comment: Thank foe youre sollution, its work. Its not exactly what i was need, but i used it in littel bit other case